# Third party iOS Developer & Agent Role

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I am currently struggling about finding out on how to deal with that specific situation and I hope you guys can help me solve the issue:

We do have web application for which we now want to offer native iOS apps. As we do not own the skills to write native iOS apps, we found an agency with a good reputation to handle this task for us.
They asked us to create an apple developer account. We did it, we got a call from Apple and we're certified as of now. So it is a company account.

Now that agency told us to submit username and password for the apple developer account. They need it to do special things, especially at the end to submit an app to the app store.

Is it really the way to go or is transferring the agent role to them temporarily a better decision? I am asking because my iCloud Account and other stuff is related to that ID.

What is the best way for such a constellation: Third-Party-Dev and corporate apple developer account?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it's ever a good idea to give your login credentials to a third party.  As a developer building applications for third party customers, here's how we handle that sort of thing at my company:

1. The customer (that would be you) creates an Enterprise Developer account with Apple
2. Using their developer account, the customer creates an App Id, a distribution certificate, and a provisioning profile and gives those three things to us
3. We develop and build the app using their certificate, and provide them with the resulting .ipa file
4. They use a distribution tool like AppBlade or MobileIron to deploy the app on their devices

In our case the customer we're building the app for is also the end user - it sounds like your situation is a bit different in that your company is not the end user but more of a middle man, selling the app to your end users.  The only real difference is the distribution method (step 4): Once the developer gives you the .ipa file built with your certificate, you could then submit it to the app store for sale to your customers, or pass the .ipa file on to your customers for deployment via some other distribution mechanism.

It's unfortunate that Apple makes it so difficult to do business this way, as it seems to be a fairly common practice.  They need to have a less roundabout way to separate development from distribution.  But for us, at least, this process seems to work and is relatively painless - it just requires some coordination between your company and the one doing the development.

I would also recommend a source code escrow agreement with the developer.  Since they'll own the source code for an application that your business depends on, you'll want to make sure you can get that source code and still build your application in the event the company doing the development goes out of business or otherwise disappears.

Comment: The client could also use the Application Loader to deploy the app to the App Store

Answer (score 0):

We also request the owner of the account to create admin account for us. So you will still have your owner account and we the developer just have a admin account. You will have to create an account for developers.apple.com and iTunesConnect.

You can use the same email address multiple times for developers.apple.com btu not for iTunesConnect. Since ItunesConnect requires unique email address we just create email account per client.